How can I run raytracing for a single frame?
I'm new to raytracing and the Vulkan library and I am trying to use raytracing for a data analysis problem rather than graphics.
I have an object file and sets of parameters for the light source and I want to know which vertices are being hit. Ultimately I want a matrix with 0 where light did not hit and 1 where light hit.
I'm having trouble with the initial setup of the pipeline without having a loop that renders at real time.
I have been looking at the tutorials but they are all focused on visualizing graphics.
https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction
It seems to me that this should be an easier problem since it is just a one shot set of rays but I am not experienced with this.
If someone knows of a tutorial that is more fitting for this problem or if they could get me started in the right direction that would be great.

Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Assuming you're talking about hardware raytracing: consider taking a look at NVIDIA's ray tracing tutorial (https://nvpro-samples.github.io/vk_raytracing_tutorial_KHR/). It requires fairly good comprehension of Vulkan though, as they assume you fully understand all the parts common with the classical modern graphics pipeline. This will be a very, very long adventure if you start from scratch, especially alone. Maybe you should consider working with a local graphics expert, that knows both Vulkan/modern graphics API and hardware raytracing.

Additional remark, still assuming you're talking about hardware raytracing and starting from scracth. Not only will you need to first understand how to even setup everything needed to use this feature (though that doesn't change much once you got the initial one working), but you will also need to learn how to write the shaders that perform what you want them to do (extract the information you need and save it somewhere), and how to read the information back from the GPU in an appropriate format and save it somewhere (). Good luck!

As for the actual problem you have, are you sure you need hardware-based GPU ray-tracing? Wouldn't something like an adaptative BVH suffice? Or something akin to Monte-Carlo Geometry Processing by Sawhney & Crane (2020)?
